# How to load large file with StreamReader in C#?

Tags: c#, list

I'm using StreamReader in C# to load a txt file into a list
it's work fine with small size file <= 20 Mb 
but when I need to load large files the prepossess stopped and show me  this

> Your app has entered a break state, but no code is currently
>   executing that is supported by the selected debug engine (e.g. only
>   native runtime code is executing).

I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

This is the code

```
line = reader.ReadLine();

while (line != null)
{
    if (line.Contains("@"))
    {
        myEmails.Add(line);
        line = reader.ReadLine();
    }
}
reader.Close();
```

Comment: If that is your actual code, once it gets to a line that does not contain "@" it will enter an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code just has a minor logical error.

In your loop, you are looking for lines containing an `@` symbol.  If the line has one, it adds it to `myEmails` and gets the next line.

However, if the line does not contain an `@`, **the next line is never read** so you enter an infinite loop.

You just need to move `line = reader.ReadLine();` outside of your `if` statement and it will always read the next line regardless of whether it contains an `@` symbol:

```
line = reader.ReadLine();
while (line != null)
{
    if (line.Contains("@"))
        myEmails.Add(line);

    line = reader.ReadLine();
}
reader.Close();
```